# Proving the number of partitions of n where each part of size k appears < k times, for all k

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

How to prove that the partitions of $n$ where each part of size $k$ appears $< k$ times is given by $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+p^k + p^{2k} + p^{3k} +\cdots+ p^{(k-1)k})$$

Comment: Are you familiar with generating functions, given that you added the tag? This is almost immediately obvious, so what have you tried / where are you stuck? (Also, check your indices, you need brackets around them)?

Comment: I though I was familiar with generating functions, but since it is not obvious to me, I guess I need to review it again. I just don't see how $p^{ik}$ indicates the number of partitions where the part of size i appears k times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generating function of the number of partitions where there are fewer than $k$ parts equal to $k$ for all $k\geq 1$ should be
$$f(p)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+p^k + p^{2k} + p^{3k} +\cdots+ p^{(k-1)k}\right).$$
The property follows just from the definition of generating function: the factor
$$p^{0k}+p^k + p^{2k} + p^{3k} +\cdots+ p^{(k-1)k}$$
implies that a part of size $k$ may appear $0,1,\dots, k-1$
times.
See also the OEIS sequence [A087153](https://oeis.org/A087153).